# wsdl2py requests

Tags: python, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to get results from a SOAP service called Chrome ADS (for vehicle data). They provided php and Java samples, but I need python (our site is in Django). My question is:

What should I be passing as a request to the SOAP service when using wsdl2py-generated classes?

Following the examples I'm using a DataVersionsRequest object as the request parameter, but the code generated by wsdl2py seems to want a getDataVersions object, and there's something like that defined at the bottom of the generated _client.py file. But that too seems to throw an error. So I'm not sure what I should be passing as the request obj.  Any suggestions?

```
$sudo apt-get install python-zsi
$wsdl2py http://platform.chrome.com/***********
$python 
>>> url = "http://platform.chrome.com/***********"
>>> from AutomotiveDescriptionService6_client import *
>>> from AutomotiveDescriptionService6_types import *
>>> locator = AutomotiveDescriptionService6Locator()
>>> service = locator.getAutomotiveDescriptionService6Port()
>>> locale = ns0.Locale_Def('locale')
>>> locale._country="US"
>>> locale._language="English"
>>> acctInfo = ns0.AccountInfo_Def('accountInfo')
>>> acctInfo._accountNumber=*****
>>> acctInfo._accountSecret="*****"
>>> acctInfo._locale = locale
>>> dataVersionsRequest = ns0.DataVersionsRequest_Dec()
>>> dataVersionsRequest._accountInfo = acctInfo
>>> service.getDataVersions(dataVersionsRequest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "AutomotiveDescriptionService6_client.py", line 36, in getDataVersions
    raise TypeError, "%s incorrect request type" % (request.__class__)
TypeError: <class 'AutomotiveDescriptionService6_types.DataVersionsRequest_Dec'> incorrect request type
>>> dataVersionsRequest = getDataVersions
>>> dataVersionsRequest._accountInfo = acctInfo
>>> service.getDataVersions(dataVersionsRequest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "AutomotiveDescriptionService6_client.py", line 36, in getDataVersions
    raise TypeError, "%s incorrect request type" % (request.__class__)
AttributeError: class DataVersionsRequest_Holder has no attribute '__class__'
>>> quit()
$cat AutomotiveDescriptionService6_client.py
.....
# Locator
class AutomotiveDescriptionService6Locator:
    AutomotiveDescriptionService6Port_address = "http://platform.chrome.com:80/AutomotiveDescriptionService/AutomotiveDescriptionService6"
    def getAutomotiveDescriptionService6PortAddress(self):
        return AutomotiveDescriptionService6Locator.AutomotiveDescriptionService6Port_address
    def getAutomotiveDescriptionService6Port(self, url=None, **kw):
        return AutomotiveDescriptionService6BindingSOAP(url or AutomotiveDescriptionService6Locator.AutomotiveDescriptionService6Port_address, **kw)

# Methods
class AutomotiveDescriptionService6BindingSOAP:
    def __init__(self, url, **kw):
        kw.setdefault("readerclass", None)
        kw.setdefault("writerclass", None)
        # no resource properties
        self.binding = client.Binding(url=url, **kw)
        # no ws-addressing

    # op: getDataVersions
    def getDataVersions(self, request, **kw):
        if isinstance(request, getDataVersions) is False:
            raise TypeError, "%s incorrect request type" % (request.__class__)
        # no input wsaction
        self.binding.Send(None, None, request, soapaction="", **kw)
        # no output wsaction
        response = self.binding.Receive(getDataVersionsResponse.typecode)
        return response
.....
getDataVersions = GED("urn:description6.kp.chrome.com", "DataVersionsRequest").pyclass
```

Also, as an aside, I'm not sure that the strings I'm passing to the pname parameter are correct, I assume that those are the ones I see inside the XML when I explore the service with SOAP UI, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be passing a class to service.getDataVersions() the second time instead of an instance (it can't be an instance if it doesn't have __class__).

What's happening is isinstance() returns false, and in the process of trying to raise a type error, an attribute error gets raised instead because it's trying to access __class__ which apparently doesn't exist.

What happens if you try:

```
>>> dataVersionsRequest = getDataVersions**()**
>>> dataVersionsRequest._accountInfo = acctInfo
>>> service.getDataVersions(dataVersionsRequest)
```

?

Based on the line:

```
if isinstance(request, getDataVersions) is False:
            raise TypeError, "%s incorrect request type" % (request.__class__)
```

it definitely looks like you should be passing an instance of getDataVersions, so you're probably on the right track.

Comment: Yeah, that seemed to fix it... now on to the next error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382650/wsdl2py-complextypes

Comment: ah, and for anybody else reading this in the future,  RUN WSDL2PY WITH THE --COMPLEXTYPE FLAG!!!
You'll discover it creates more methods inside of each request object, that allow you to create them from the request object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to be instantiating your definition objects and then populating them. Look for type == pyclass_type objects associated with the request you're wanting to make and instantiate them.

e.g. (just guessing)

```
>>> versionrequest = getDataVersions()
>>> versionrequest.AccountInfo = versionrequest.new_AccountInfo()
>>> versionrequest.AccountInfo.accountNumber = "123"
>>> versionrequest.AccountInfo.accountSecret = "shhhh!"
>>> service.getDataVersions(versionrequest)
```

I found that the code generated by wsdl2py was too slow for my purposes. Good luck.

Comment: hmm, so is it faster to just use SOAPpy after all?  I tried wsdl2py because when I tried passing SOAPpy a dict it errored out. I'm a little lost on how to proceed with teaching myself SOAP, and implementing it for this project.... on a deadline.

Comment: Yeah, it's a steep learning curve. Have a look at https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ while I try to remember where that "Where was this when I was trying to understand SOAP?!" document I read recently is. It might have been on the suds site.

Comment: Seconding Suds, with the caveat I just found it yesterday. I was getting similar errors from SOAPpy, but Suds had no problem parsing stuff.

Comment: gah, I was wondering what that new_accountInfo() method was.... You need to run wsdl2py with the --complexTypes argument in order to get those. Otherwise it's prematurely optimized to not include those useful methods.
That's what was missing all this time, one flag!